# How to Convert base16 to base 64 in java and vice versa?

Tags: java, base64

How to convert base16 to base64 nad vice versa in java?can anyone help me by providing the code.

the value in `base16` is : `567a3b23b683d8488d5d40d2a56e31d2`
the value in `base64` is : `Vno7I7aD2EiNXUDSpW4x0g==`

i'm expecting to get the 2nd value if i provided 1st one as input and convert `base16` to `base64`.

i'm getting the result on this [website](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex) 
if i provide these values.

the value in `base16` is : `567a3b23b683d8488d5d40d2a56e31d2` .
the value in `base64` is : `Vno7I7aD2EiNXUDSpW4x0g==`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries, the easiest thing would be to let something like Apache Commons Codec do the heavy lifting - decode the input using [`Hex`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) and then encode it using [`Base64`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html):

```
String base16input = "567a3b23b683d8488d5d40d2a56e31d2";
byte[] decoded = new Hex().decodeHex(base16input);
String base64output = new String(new Base64().encode(decoded));
```